# java.io.IOException: Frame size [...] larger than max length [...]!

Tags: apache-spark, alluxio

I am running Spark in Standalone mode + Alluxio for data access. More specifically, I have 1 spark master & 1 spark worker.

When running my job I am getting the following error:

```
17/03/22 14:35:43 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, 10.254.22.6): java.io.IOException: Frame size (67108864) larger than max length (16777216)!
        at alluxio.AbstractClient.checkVersion(AbstractClient.java:112)
        at alluxio.AbstractClient.connect(AbstractClient.java:175)
        at alluxio.AbstractClient.retryRPC(AbstractClient.java:322)
        at alluxio.client.file.FileSystemMasterClient.getStatus(FileSystemMasterClient.java:183)
        at alluxio.client.file.BaseFileSystem.getStatus(BaseFileSystem.java:175)
        at alluxio.client.file.BaseFileSystem.getStatus(BaseFileSystem.java:167)
        at alluxio.hadoop.HdfsFileInputStream.<init>(HdfsFileInputStream.java:86)
        at alluxio.hadoop.AbstractFileSystem.open(AbstractFileSystem.java:514)
        at alluxio.hadoop.FileSystem.open(FileSystem.java:25)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.open(FileSystem.java:766)
        at net.atos.hadoop.ImageRecordReader.initialize(ImageRecordReader.java:47)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD$$anon$1.<init>(NewHadoopRDD.scala:153)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD.compute(NewHadoopRDD.scala:124)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD.compute(NewHadoopRDD.scala:65)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:300)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:264)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:300)
        at org.apache.spark.CacheManager.getOrCompute(CacheManager.scala:69)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:262)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:300)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:264)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:300)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:264)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:73)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:88)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Environment:

- Spark 1.5.2
- Alluxio 1.3.0

Answer (score 0):

I had `SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY` set to `2G` on both master and worker (passing it as an environment variable, see [this section of the documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.2/spark-standalone.html#cluster-launch-scripts)). I was trying to increase it to `4G`. However, I only changed the parameter for the worker. I guess it caused a mismatch between master & worker.

Setting it to the same value (`4G`) on both nodes solved the problem.